# How to find an object by part of a string?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have objects like this inside an array:

```
{
  "objectId": "566013c860b202595a4b6fd9",
  "createdAt": "2015-12-03T10:04:56.367Z",
},
```

I'm using Underscore's `_.where` to find them based on `createAt`:

```
var adminsThisMonth = _.where(admins, {createdAt: adminCreatedAt})
```

Is there any way to find an object only based on one section of `createdAt`, say, the two digits between the hyphens? (`12` in this case).

Comment: `if (obj.createdAt.indexOf('-12-') > -1) { ...`

Comment: @Tushar I should put that inside the `_.where` function?

Comment: If your object is exactly as shown in OP, there's no need of `_.where`

Comment: It seems you have an array of objects. What you need is the `filter` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `_.filter()` to which you can pass a predicate function to filter the object with any logic you want.

```
_.filter(admins, function (obj) {
    return checkConditon(obj.created);
});
```

Comment: I am typing on a tram on a mobile. Braces with my shoulder.

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = {
  "objectId": "566013c860b202595a4b6fd9",
  "createdAt": "2015-12-03T10:04:56.367Z",
};

if(obj.hasOwnProperty("createdAt") && obj.createdAt.indexOf("-12-")>-1){
   ...
}
```

Checking first whether it has the key or not and if it has that key then check for the index of `-12-`

Answer (score 1):

Use the Method find, it is similar to where but takes an function as a second parameter. Then use the suggested code from @Tushar inside that function.

```
_.find(admins, function(admin) { 
    return admin.createdAt.indexOf('-12-') > -1;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use plain JS like this:

```
var admins =[
    {
      "objectId": "566013c860b202595a4b6fd9",
      "createdAt": "2015-12-03T10:04:56.367Z",
    }
]


var checkCreatedAt = (admins.map(function(obj){ return obj.createdAt; }).toString().indexOf("-12-") != -1) ? true : false;
```

...then you can use `checkCreatedAt` as you wish.